# Custom Class View for UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uibutton

In Identity Inspector, I want to set a custom class for my `UIButton`.
Thus I create my custom class that is a `UIView` but my custom class doesn't appears on the list. 
Vice-versa, if I add a `UIView`, on the list appears most class included `UIButton`.

If `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`, and not a `UIView` is a `UIButton`,
why is it possible and why can't I use my `UIView` custom class for representing my `UIButton`?

Comment: I would not recommend subclassing UIButton but if you want to do it anyway, create your customClass inherited from UIButton, not UIView. Then it will appear in identity inspector

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure entirely what you mean but I'll have a go.

Your question ...

> If UIButton is a subclass of UIView, and not a UIView is a UIButton, why it's possible and why I can't use my UIView custom class for representing my UIButton.

I believe you are saying...

1. `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`.
2. Your custom view is a subclass of `UIView`.
3. Why can't you set your `UIButton` to be your custom view?

Is that right?

If so, it's fairly clear. Just because they are derived from the same class does not mean they are related. A `UILabel` is also derived from `UIView` but is very different.

If you want to create a custom subclass of `UIButton` then your custom class should derive from `UIButton`...

You should have...

```
@interface YourSubclass: UIButton
```

Instead of...

```
@interface YourSubclass: UIView
```

Doing this will make the custom subclass appear in the Identity Inspector in Interface Builder.

Comment: Ok I understand, and in UIView list I show UIButton because of it is a subclass uf UIView. Sorry for the simple question, i'm a newbie

Answer (score 2):

> You can create a custom subclass for a UIButton. Then set it as Custom Class for any button.

```
class CCButton: UIButton {

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        createBorder()
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createBorder()
    }

    private func createBorder(){
        //Define Layer
        self.layer.cornerRadius  = 8.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```